# Trigger Keith Wood's jquery datepicker's "Today/Prev/Next" button click in angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I am using Keith Wood Jquery.datepicker.min.js v5.0.1 with AngularJS directive.
I have to change CSS of date values based on "Today/Prev/Next" button click.
So, I want to trigger click functionality in directive. I tried binding the class of above buttons as below:

My Code:

```
<input tabindex="8" class="date" max-date="{{c.enddate}}" required type="text" id="begindate" name="begindate" date-picker ng-model="c.begindate" />
 <label for="begindate">Begin Date</label>
```

Directive code:

```
restrict: 'A',
link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    var dpToday = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.datepick-cmd-today' ) );
    dpToday.bind("click", function () {
         console.log ("dpToday clicked: ");
    });
    var updateModel = function () {
        var dt = element.val();
        if(controller){
            controller.$setViewValue(dt);
        }

        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }

    if (controller != null) {
        controller.$render = function () {
            element.val(controller.$viewValue);
            return controller.$viewValue;
        };
    }
    attrs.$observe('minDate', function (value) {
        element.datepick('option', 'minDate', value);
    });
    attrs.$observe('maxDate', function (value) {
        element.datepick('option', 'maxDate', value);
    });
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your directive code right? There is a quotation in line 6 that should not to be there.

Comment: @RicardoPontual I mistakenly put. I will edit it.